# how to solve this in non thread method "Exception in thread "main" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException"

Tags: java, dictionary

I am trying to remove value from the map which is iterated when i try this i get the following exception .

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
```

My code is below.

```
public static Map removeHolyday(Map daysMap,Map holydayMap){
        Iterator<Map.Entry> workingDays = daysMap.entrySet().iterator();
          while (workingDays.hasNext()) {
              Map.Entry workingDaysEntry = workingDays.next();
              System.out.println("Key = " + workingDaysEntry.getKey() + ", Value = " + workingDaysEntry.getValue());
              Iterator<Map.Entry> holydays = daysMap.entrySet().iterator();
              while (holydays.hasNext()) {
                  Map.Entry holydayEntry = holydays.next();
                  if(workingDaysEntry.getKey().toString().equals(holydayEntry.getKey().toString())){
                      daysMap.remove(workingDaysEntry.getKey().toString());
                  }
              }
          }
        return daysMap;
    }
```

Please help me to solve this.

EDIT :

this is the code i use but the value is not gettig deleted from map;

```
package sample;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap;

class Workindays {
    public static int findNoOfDays(int year, int month, int day) {
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        System.out.println("month : " + month);
        calendar.set(year, month - 1, day);
        int days = calendar.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        System.out.println("days :"+days);
        return days;
    }
    public static Map getHolydaysMap(int year, int month, int day) {
        //connect with database and check whether the date is holyday query is = SELECT * FROM holiday_calendar h WHERE date >='2008-10-01' AND date <='2008-10-30' AND type='Fixed';
        Map holydaysMap = new ConcurrentHashMap(); 
        holydaysMap.put("17","17-04-2012");
        holydaysMap.put("25","25-04-2012");
        return holydaysMap;
    }
    public static Map getWorkingDaysMap(int year, int month, int day){
        int totalworkingdays=0,noofdays=0;
        String nameofday = "";
        Map workingDaysMap = new HashMap();
        Map holyDayMap = new ConcurrentHashMap();
        noofdays = findNoOfDays(year,month,day);
        holyDayMap = getHolydaysMap(year,month,day);

        for (int i = 1; i <= noofdays; i++) {
            Date date = (new GregorianCalendar(year,month - 1, i)).getTime(); // year,month,day
            SimpleDateFormat f = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE");
            nameofday = f.format(date);
            String formatedDate = i + "-" + month + "-" + year;
            if(!(nameofday.equals("Saturday") || nameofday.equals("Sunday"))){
                workingDaysMap.put(i,formatedDate);
                totalworkingdays++;
            }
        }
        workingDaysMap.put("totalworkingdays", totalworkingdays);
        System.out.println("removeHolyday : "+removeHolyday(workingDaysMap,holyDayMap));
        return workingDaysMap;
    }

    public static Map removeHolyday(Map daysMap,Map holydayMap){
        Iterator<Map.Entry> holyDayiterator = holydayMap.entrySet().iterator();
          while (holyDayiterator.hasNext()) {
              Map.Entry holyDayEntry = holyDayiterator.next();
             Iterator<Map.Entry> daysiterator = daysMap.entrySet().iterator();

             while (daysiterator.hasNext()) {
                  Map.Entry daysEntry = daysiterator.next();
                  if(daysEntry.getKey().equals(holyDayEntry.getKey()))
                      daysMap.remove(holyDayEntry.getKey());
              }
          }
System.out.println(daysMap);
        return daysMap;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String delimiter = null, dateValues[] = null, startDate = "01-04-2012";
        int year = 0,month=0,day=0,totalworkingdays = 0;
        Map workingDaysMap = new LinkedHashMap();

        startDate = "01-04-2012";
        delimiter = "-";
        dateValues = startDate.split(delimiter);

        year = Integer.parseInt(dateValues[2]);
        month = Integer.parseInt(dateValues[1]);
        day = Integer.parseInt(dateValues[0]);

        workingDaysMap = getWorkingDaysMap(year, month, day);
        System.out.println("workingdays map : "+workingDaysMap);

    }
}
```

working code :

```
package sample;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap;

public class Main {
    public static Map removeHolyday(Map daysMap,Map holydayMap){
        Iterator<Map.Entry> holyDayiterator = holydayMap.entrySet().iterator();
          while (holyDayiterator.hasNext()) {
              Map.Entry holyDayEntry = holyDayiterator.next();
             Iterator<Map.Entry> daysiterator = daysMap.entrySet().iterator();

             while (daysiterator.hasNext()) {
                  Map.Entry daysEntry = daysiterator.next();
                  if(daysEntry.getKey().equals(holyDayEntry.getKey()))
                      daysMap.remove(holyDayEntry.getKey());
              }
          }
System.out.println(daysMap);
        return daysMap;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Map holydaysMap = new ConcurrentHashMap(); 
        holydaysMap.put("17", "17-04-2012");
        holydaysMap.put("25", "25-04-2012");

    Map holydayMap = new HashMap(); 
    holydayMap.put("17", "17-04-2012");
    holydayMap.put("25", "25-04-2012");
    holydayMap.put("3", "03-04-2012");
    holydayMap.put("4", "04-04-2012");

    removeHolyday(holydayMap, holydaysMap);

}
}
```

Regards
Antony

Comment: Perhaps [Map.containsKey(Object key)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#containsKey(java.lang.Object)) and [Map.remove(Object key)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#remove(java.lang.Object)) is prefered to remove the objects in `daysMap`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, it's actually pretty easy - just change this line:

```
daysMap.remove(workingDaysEntry.getKey().toString());
```

to:

```
workingDays.remove();
```

While you're iterating over a collection, you can *only* make changes to it via the iterator's `remove()` method, basically. Note that some iterators don't support removal - hopefully the implementation of map you're using does...

EDIT: I suspect you've got another bug, actually. This line:

```
Iterator<Map.Entry> holydays = daysMap.entrySet().iterator();
```

should probably be:

```
Iterator<Map.Entry> holydays = holydayMap.entrySet().iterator();
```

At the moment you're not even using `holydayMap`. You should also break after the call to `remove()` - you can't remove the same entry twice.

EDIT: I think I've found the problem now, and you'd have found it yourself if you were using generics. The `holyDayMap` keys are all strings:

```
Map holydaysMap = new ConcurrentHashMap(); 
holydaysMap.put("17","17-04-2012");
holydaysMap.put("25","25-04-2012");
```

... but the working day map keys are integers:

```
    for (int i = 1; i <= noofdays; i++) {
        ...
        workingDaysMap.put(i,formatedDate);
    }
```

Now "17" isn't the same as 17, so no entries will match. If you declared your maps with their key/value types, you'd spot this earlier.

Note that your "working" code sample *doesn't* have this problem - it uses strings everywhere.

(You should really consider whether strings are the right values to use to start with - consider using [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sf.net) and `LocalDate` for date representations...)

EDIT: Here's a short but complete program which shows `remove()` working:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        map.put("foo1", "a");
        map.put("foo2", "b");
        map.put("bar1", "c");
        map.put("bar2", "d");
        map.put("foo3", "e");
        System.out.println("Before: " + map);

        Iterator<String> iterator = map.keySet().iterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            if (iterator.next().startsWith("foo")) {
                iterator.remove();
            }
        }
        System.out.println("After: " + map);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Before: {foo3=e, foo2=b, foo1=a, bar1=c, bar2=d}
After: {bar1=c, bar2=d}
```

So you need to work out why *your* code doesn't behave that way.

Answer (score 1):

Construct first map(daysMap) as `ConcurrentHashMap` and change your method signature  to like this :

```
public static Map removeHolyday(ConcurrentHashMap daysMap,Map holydayMap){
```