# remove is not working in hashmap in java?

Tags: java, hashmap

Hi all I have been trying to fix this but could not fix, the problem is remove is not working in hashmap.

Please see the below code.

```
 package com.org.common;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap;

@SuppressWarnings("unused")
class Workindays {
    public static int findNoOfDays(int year, int month, int day) {
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.set(year, month - 1, day);
        int days = calendar.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        return days;
    }
    public static Map<String, String> getHolydaysMap(int year, int month, int day) {
        //connect with database and check whether the date is holyday query is = SELECT * FROM holiday_calendar h WHERE date >='2008-10-01' AND date <='2008-10-30' AND type='Fixed';
        Map<String, String> holydaysMap = new LinkedHashMap<String,String>(); 

        holydaysMap.put("20","17-04-2012");
        holydaysMap.put("10","25-04-2012");
        return holydaysMap;
    }
    public static Map<String, String> getWorkingDaysMap(int year, int month, int day){
        int totalworkingdays=0,noofdays=0;
        String nameofday = "";
        ConcurrentHashMap<String,String> workingDaysMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<String,String>();
        Map<String,String> holyDayMap = new LinkedHashMap<String,String>();
        noofdays = findNoOfDays(year,month,day);
        holyDayMap = getHolydaysMap(year,month,day);

        for (int i = 1; i <= noofdays; i++) {
            Date date = (new GregorianCalendar(year,month - 1, i)).getTime(); // year,month,day
            SimpleDateFormat f = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE");
            nameofday = f.format(date);
            String formatedDate = i+"-"+month+"-"+year;
            if(!(nameofday.equals("Saturday") || nameofday.equals("Sunday"))){
                workingDaysMap.put(String.valueOf(i),formatedDate);
                totalworkingdays++;
            }
        }
        workingDaysMap.put("totalworkingdays", String.valueOf(totalworkingdays));

        System.out.println("removeHolyday : "+removeHoliday(workingDaysMap,holyDayMap));
        return workingDaysMap;
    }
    @SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes", "unchecked" })
    public static Map removeHoliday(ConcurrentHashMap daysMap, Map holydayMap) {
        Iterator<Map.Entry> holyDayiterator = holydayMap.entrySet().iterator();
        while (holyDayiterator.hasNext()) {
            Map.Entry holyDayEntry = holyDayiterator.next();

            Iterator<Map.Entry> daysiterator = daysMap.entrySet().iterator();
            while (daysiterator.hasNext()) {
                Map.Entry daysEntry = daysiterator.next();
                 if(daysEntry.getKey().equals(holyDayEntry.getKey()))
                      daysMap.remove(holyDayEntry.getKey());
            }
        }
        return daysMap;
    }
    @SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes" })
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String delimiter = null, dateValues[] = null, startDate = "01-04-2012";
        int year = 0,month=0,day=0,totalworkingdays = 0;
        Map workingDaysMap = new LinkedHashMap<String,String>();

        startDate = "01-04-2012";
        delimiter = "-";
        dateValues = startDate.split(delimiter);

        year = Integer.parseInt(dateValues[2]);
        month = Integer.parseInt(dateValues[1]);
        day = Integer.parseInt(dateValues[0]);

        workingDaysMap = getWorkingDaysMap(year, month, day);
        //System.out.println("workingdays map : "+workingDaysMap);

    }
}
```

this is the method i call to remove a value

```
removeHolyday
```

I have just given sample value to test in the following method.

```
getHolydaysMap
```

Please help.

EDIT : 
Thanks guys for all who have taken their valueable time to answer, upvote and downvote.i have changed the code and it is working fine now,

updated working code.

Regards
Antony

Comment: Please shorten down your question. Stackoverflow is not gonna read through all that code.

Comment: As Anto I also dont get every point of the code example you give, but are you sure the keys in your holyDays Map are Integer instances?

Comment: "HashMap.remove" doesn't work?! You mean, your code doesn't work... right?

Comment: And that getKey -> Integer -> int -> Integer conversion is pretty suspicious...

Comment: First, you need to start using Generics. You are having to do  `Integer.parseInt(holyDayEntry.getKey().toString())` everywhere because your Map is defined as `Map` instead of `Map<Integer, String>`

Comment: Have a look at your thread - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10698224/how-to-solve-this-in-non-thread-method-exception-in-thread-main-java-util-con

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use ConcurrentHashMap  to do this,

public static Map removeHolyday(ConcurrentHashMap daysMap,Map holydayMap){

EDIT : use the following code to do,

```
public static Map removeHoliday(ConcurrentHashMap daysMap, Map holydayMap) {
        Iterator<Map.Entry> holyDayiterator = holydayMap.entrySet().iterator();
        while (holyDayiterator.hasNext()) {
            Map.Entry holyDayEntry = holyDayiterator.next();
            if(daysMap.containsKey(holyDayEntry.getKey())){
                daysMap.remove(holyDayEntry.getKey());
            }
        }
        return daysMap;
    }
```

Comment: No need to check `containsKey`, remove will not do anything if the key is not found. Why use `entrySet` when only the keys are used? No need to use an `Iterator` when a `for each` loop will work.

Answer (score 2):

```
  if (Integer.parseInt(daysEntry.getKey().toString()) ==   Integer.parseInt(holyDayEntry.getKey().toString()))
                daysMap.remove( Integer.parseInt(holyDayEntry.getKey().toString()));
            break;
```

If condition fails than it will break out instead of looping for rest of Map

Comment: +1 Looks like the right answer to me. That said, the method is WAY too complex. There is no need for the inner loop.

Answer (score 2):

You don't state the specific error you're having, but there are a couple of general comments to be made.

Your break statement is outside the "if" so the code will go through then exit the while loop after the first key.  In other words, you're not actually iterating over all the keys.

Secondly, you don't *need* to iterate the map and test for the matching key, calling remove will do this for you anyway.

Thirdly (as a point of interest) removing items from a map while iterating over it will result in an exception from the iterator the next time around the loop.  Not highlighted in this particular case as the break statement saves you from reaching the error, but worth noting for future.

Answer (score 1):

in your removeHoliday method you need parantheses; you need the following:

```
if (Integer.parseInt(daysEntry.getKey().toString()) == Integer.parseInt(holyDayEntry.getKey().toString())) {
    daysMap.remove( Integer.parseInt(holyDayEntry.getKey().toString()));
    break;
}
```

in stead of

```
if (Integer.parseInt(daysEntry.getKey().toString()) ==     Integer.parseInt(holyDayEntry.getKey().toString()))
    daysMap.remove( Integer.parseInt(holyDayEntry.getKey().toString()));
break;
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider rewriting `removeHolydays` as such:

Instead of

```
  public static Map removeHolyday(Map daysMap, Map holydayMap) {
    Iterator<Map.Entry> holyDayiterator = holydayMap.entrySet().iterator();
    while (holyDayiterator.hasNext()) {
        Map.Entry holyDayEntry = holyDayiterator.next();
        Iterator<Map.Entry> daysiterator = daysMap.entrySet().iterator();

        while (daysiterator.hasNext()) {
            Map.Entry daysEntry = daysiterator.next();
            if (Integer.parseInt(daysEntry.getKey().toString()) == Integer.parseInt(holyDayEntry.getKey().toString()))
                daysMap.remove( Integer.parseInt(holyDayEntry.getKey().toString()));
            break;
        }
    }
    return daysMap;
}
```

It should be:

```
public static Map<Integer, String> remove(Map<Integer, String> daysMap, Map<Integer, String> holydayMap){
     for(Integer i : holydayMap.keySet())
         daysMap.remove(i);
     return daysMap;
}
```

This will get rid of the error of having the `break` in the wrong place as pointed out by `ejb_guy`